# Type Error in Dictionary method map while calling a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am getting a `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` when i am trying to call the function "capitalize"

here are the initial dictionaries and data needed

```
import pandas as pd

data= [["English","john","smith","ohio","united states","tesla","test@gmail.com","manufacturing","National","Residental","","TRUE","FALSE"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

lang_trans= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}

states_dict= {"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK", "Arizona": "AZ", "Arkansas": "AR", "California": "CA", "Colorado": "CO", "Connecticut": "CT", "Delaware": "DE", "Florida": "FL", "Georgia": "GA", "Hawaii": "HI", "Idaho": "ID", "Illinois": "IL", "Indiana": "IN", "Iowa": "IA", "Kansas": "KS", "Kentucky": "KY", "Louisiana": "LA", "Maine": "ME", "Maryland": "MD", "Massachusetts": "MA", "Michigan": "MI", "Minnesota": "MN", "Mississippi": "MS", "Missouri": "MO", "Montana": "MT", "Nebraska": "NE", "Nevada": "NV", "New Hampshire": "NH", "New Jersey": "NJ", "New Mexico": "NM", "New York": "NY", "North Carolina": "NC", "North Dakota": "ND", "Ohio": "OH", "Oklahoma": "OK", "Oregon": "OR", "Pennsylvania": "PA", "Rhode Island": "RI", "South Carolina": "SC", "South Dakota": "SD", "Tennessee": "TN", "Texas": "TX", "Utah": "UT", "Vermont": "VT", "Virginia": "VA", "Washington": "WA", "West Virginia": "WV", "Wisconsin": "WI", "Wyoming": "WY", "District of Columbia": "DC", "Washington DC": "DC"}
```

here is all of the functions I have

```
# this is supposed to make str.title() all the columns in the dictionary with the function 'capitalize'

def capitalize(col):
    if col.notna().any():
        return col.str.title()
    return col

#this is supposed to replace the values in the 'communication_lang_c' column with the abbreviated value found in the lang_trans dictionary

def lang(df_lang, column, lang_dict):
    for k, v in lang_dict.items():
        df_lang[column] = df[column].replace(k,v)
    return df_lang

#this is similar to lang where its supposed to replace the values in df[states] with the abbreviated value found in states_dict

def states(df_states, column, states_dict):
    for i,j in states_dict.items():
        df_states[column]=df[column].replace(i,j)
    return df_states

def req_cols (col):
    #TODO
    return col

def valid(col):
    #TODO
    return col
```

here is the method dictionary

```
parsing_map={
"firstName": [req_cols, capitalize],
"lastName": [req_cols, capitalize],
"state":[valid, states,capitalize],
"Communication_Language__c": lang,
"country": [req_cols,valid,capitalize],
"company":req_cols,
"email":req_cols,
"industry":[valid,capitalize],
"SME_Vertical__c":valid,
"System_Type__c":[valid,capitalize],
"AccountType":[valid,capitalize],
"customerSegment":capitalize,
"Existing_Customer__c":req_cols,
"GDPR_Email_Permission__c":req_cols
}
```

and finally here is where i call all of the functions, this is where i think my error is coming from

```
for col_name, fns in parsing_map.items():
    for fn in fns:
        df[col_name] = fn(df[col_name])

#transforming communication_lang_c
df = lang(df, 'Communication_Language__c' ,lang_trans)

#transforming state
df = states(df, 'state', states_dict)
```

I am getting `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` once the `for col_name, fns`... starts and it gets stuck on 'communication_langauge_c'

How do I call my capitalize function so it does not give me a type error from the others in the dictionary that does not hae the function 'capitalized' assigned to it?

my desired output

```
data= [["ENG","John","Smith","OH","United States","tesla","test@gmail.com","Manufacturing","National","Residental","","TRUE","FALSE"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])
```

Comment: Not all the values of `parsing_map` are lists. Sometimes they are a single function. Make them all lists (even if a list of only one element) by making sure they are all wrapped in braces. I.E.: `"Communication_Language__c": [lang]`

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details, including a stack trace. Anyway, BorrajaX is right. The error '...is not iterable' clearly says that.